# How to make Prolog depth-first-search algorithm go deeper into the tree? (Applied to Sokoban)

Tags: prolog, depth-first-search, backtracking

I'm trying to solve the [Sokoban puzzle](http://es.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sokoban) in Prolog using a depth-first-search algorithm, but I cannot manage to search the solution tree in depth. I'm able to explore only the first level.

All the sources are at [Github](https://github.com/jgsogo/sokoban/tree/bd831ecbf713a4c5816dbbe9dfaf16de8d94f334) (links to revision when the question was asked) so feel free to explore and test them. I divided the rules into several files:

- **board.pl**: contains rules related to the board: directions, neighbourhoods,...
- **game.pl**: this file states the rules about movements, valid positions,...
- **level1.pl**: defines the board, position of the boxes and solution squares for a sample game.
- **sokoban.pl**: *tries* to implement dfs :(

I know I need to go deeper when a new state is created instead of checking if it is the final state and backtracking... I need to continue moving, it is impossible to reach the final state with only one movement.

Any help/advice will be highly appreciated, I've been playing around without improvements.

Thanks!

PS.- ¡Ah! I'm working with SWI-Prolog, just in case it makes some difference

PS.- I'm really newbie to Prolog, and maybe I'm facing an obvious mistake, but this is the reason I'm asking here.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easy to fix: In `sokoban.pl`, predicate `solve_problem/2`, you are limiting the solution to lists of a single element in the goal:

```
   solve_dfs(Problem, Initial, [Initial], [Solution])
```

Instead, you probably mean:

```
    solve_dfs(Problem, Initial, [Initial], Solution)
```

because a solution can consist of many moves.

In fact, an even better search strategy is often *iterative deepening*, which you get with:

```
    length(Solution, _),
    solve_dfs(Problem, Initial, [Initial], Solution)
```

Iterative deepening is a *complete* search strategy and an *optimal* strategy under quite general assumptions.

Other than that, I recommend you cut down the significant number of impure I/O calls in your program. There are just too many predicates where you write something on the screen.

Instead, focus on a clear declarative description, and cleanly separate the output from a description of what a solution looks like. In fact, let the *toplevel* do the printing for you: Describe what a solution looks like (you are already doing this), and let the toplevel display the solution as variable bindings. Also, think declaratively, and use better names like `dfs_moves/4`, `problem_solution/2` instead of `solve_dfs/4`, `solve_problem/2` etc.

DCGs may also help you in some places of your code to more conveniently describe lists.

+1 for tackling a nice and challenging search problem with Prolog!

Comment: Thanks! It worked, now I get the two natural solutions for the purposed *level1*.

The code is so verbose because I thought it will help me to follow the execution (I'm an *imperative* boy). Now that I have an answer, I'll focus on your comments and advices and I may come later with doubts.

Thanks!